# Conversion from a derived class pointer to a base class pointer is not working when files are split into .cpp and .h files

Tags: c++, header-files

Shape.h

```
#include"Circle.h"
#include"Square.h"
class Shape {
public:
    virtual void Draw() = 0;        
    static Shape* Create(std::string type);
};
```

Shape.cpp

```
#include "Shape.h"
Shape* Shape::Create(string type) {
    if ( type == "circle" ) return new Circle();
    if ( type == "square" ) return new Square();
    return NULL;
}
```

Circle.cpp

```
#include "Circle.h"
void Circle::Draw() {
    cout << "I am circle" << endl;
}
```

Circle.h

```
#include"Shape.h"
class Circle:public Shape {
public:
    void Draw();
    friend class Shape;
};
```

Square.cpp

```
#include "Square.h"
void Square::Draw() {
    cout << "I am Square" << endl;
}
```

Square.h

```
#include"Shape.h"
class Square:public Shape {
public:
    void Draw();
    friend class Shape;
};
```

It throws this error:
Square.h error: expected class-name before { token [for the inheritance it does not identify Shape]

But the same code works if it is in a monolithic file(without the .cpp and .h) a single main.cpp file
What is that I am missing with including header files?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `#include "Square.h"` and `#include "Circle.h"` from `Shape.h`.

`Square` and `Circle` depend on a definition of `Shape` because they both inherit from `Shape` but `Shape` can - and must - be defined before `Square` and `Circle` are defined so including definitions of `Circle` and `Square` before you define `Shape` is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure how to control the order of definition. Shape should know about Square and Circle to return the pointer in the Create function. Forward declaration is also throwing error - forward declaration of struct Circle

Comment: @bhadrinathpani: You can `#include` `Circle.h` and `Square.h` from `Shape.cpp` where you define `Shape::Create`, you just can't include them from `Shape.h` before you've defined `class Shape`.

Comment: Is that a good practice to include files in .cpp other than the corresponding .h file(Shape.h). Is there something wrong with my design of class.

Comment: @bhadrinathpani: You should include what you need from Shape.cpp. It's good design to only include from the .cpp if you don't need to include from the corresponding .h.

Comment: In this case its the only option but is this(adding .h in .cpp files) what good programmers always do? I was of the opinion that good code should have its .h files(Circle.h,Square.h) in one file(Shape.h) and the includes should be order independent. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @bhadrinathpani: Yes it is and yes, header files should be order independent so they should always include other headers that they depend on but they should minimize the dependencies they pass on to their clients so shouldn't include anything that they don't depend on.

Answer (score 2):

You created a circular inclusion. `Shape.h` is including `Circle.h` and `Square.h`. `Circle.h` and `Square.h` include `Shape.h`. This does not make any sense.

Apparently you are also using include guards of some sort, which you are not showing to us here (if you didn't the error would be different). The include guards make sure that `Shape.h` is not included into itself. The result is that `Square.h` is included into `Shape.h` before the definition of `Shape`, which is why you get the error.

Circular inclusion is always useless. Why is

```
#include "Circle.h"
#include "Square.h"
```

present in `Shape.h`? What are these includes doing there? You have to make sure that you do not include `Circle.h` and `Square.h` into `Shape.h`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the guards are the usual Eclipse added stuff. On not including Circle.h and Square.h into Shape.h I get different errors: Shape.cpp: error: expected type-specifier before Circle Shape.cpp: error: cannot convert int* to Shape* in return ../Shape.cpp: error: expected â€˜;â€™ before â€˜Circleâ€™ ../Shape.cpp: error: â€˜Circleâ€™ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @phcd: You might try including `Circle.h` and `Square.h` into `Shape.cpp`. However, a better idea would be to redesign the whole thing to make sure that `Shape` knows noting about `Square` or `Circle`. Your `Shape::Create(string type)` method should not be member of `Shape`. Better make it a standalone function and move it out of `Shape.cpp`.